# How to use goto command in if choice?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running the following program ,

```
@echo off
color 0a
cls
:MENU
echo What do you want to do ?
echo.
echo 1- Flash
echo 2- Wipe
echo 3- Check
echo 4- Go Back
echo.
set /p choice=
if %choice%==1 goto 1
if %choice%==2 goto 2
if %choice%==3 goto 3
if %choice%==4 goto 4
echo Invalid Choice
goto MENU
:1 
flash.bat
:2
wipe.bat
:3 
check.bat
:4
back.bat
```

In this program when i press any other key other than 1,2,3,4 it need to show invalid choice. But, its not working.. its shows error "goto command was unexpected at this time".

Please help me guys..When pressing anyother key it need to show invalid choice. Pls help guys...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077840/goto-was-unexpected-at-this-time-batch)

Comment: but, am not facing error with pressing 1,2,3,4 ... My problem is...when pressing other keys its need to say invalid key pressed. But, its shows goto command was unexpected (at the end command) not the goto command next to 1,2,3and4 (those works) .. But, when pressing other keys other than mentions doesn't works, not showing 'invalid choice'

Comment: Noticed one thing , only pressing enter key at first goes straight to the next command line. How to stop it ? mean pressing 5,6,7 or any letter working fine by showing "invalid choice" but , only pressing enter leads to the next command or goto was not expected at this time (error)

Comment: Don't use `set /p` but `choice.exe` see `help choice` or read [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)

Comment: This is working as expected on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Have you tried changing the label names to **alphabetic** characters instead of numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest, using [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html), which does errorhandling on it's own, so you don't have to deal with that. There are many ways (many possible inputs) to break your script when using `set /p`.

If you want to keep with `set /p`, at least preset the variable (`set /p` doesn't set the variable to "empty" when you press `ENTER`, but lets it unchanged):

```
set choice=4
set /p choice=
echo %choice%
...
```

Additional bonus: you have a default action.